# Взаимосвязь понятий Сервис и API

Tags: терминология, сервисы

Есть ли у общепринятое определение понятий [«Сервис»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/service) и [«API»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/api)? Опишите их терминологию.

В частности интересует:

- само ли собой разумеется, что некоторая программа, претендующая на то, чтобы называться именно Сервисом, обязательно должна иметь API?
- существуют ли в принципе такие Сервисы, у которых нет API?

Comment: А что собственно мешает сервису быть "замкнутым"? Если нет необходимости ни рапортовать, ни управляться... С другой стороны, если сервис - то как минимум должен уметь корректно сообщить свой статус или выгрузиться по сигналу диспетчера служб - а это формально уже API.

Comment: тут стоит определиться в терминологии. так как каждый понимает это по своему.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman вопрос об общепринятой терминологии, если таковая существует в принципе.

Comment: по моему опыту лучше описать терминологию. так как только в этом случае она станет общепринятой среди тех кто услышит ее.

Answer (score 1):

Попробую...

Сервис (служба - в дословном переводе) это такая себе служебная программа, выполняющая конкретную задачу (задачи)

API (программный интерфейс) - набор функций для ВНЕШНЕГО использования.

Сервис делает дело без лишнего "шума", API принимает запрос и, в принципе также делает дело, но отдает результаты НАРУЖУ

Считаю, что разница во взаимодействии с окружением. Сервис наружу почти не смотрит, в отличие от API

Comment: "Фоновость" это скорее специфическое понимание Сервисов в Windows. В русской традиции их и называют специальным термином — Службы, противопоставляя Сервисам. О каких-нибудь Веб-Сервисах нельзя сказать, что они мол наружу не смотрят.